# How can we add ASP.NET Machine account in windows server 2003

Tags: asp.net

I wand to download the files in Windows server 2003. For that the ASP.Net application needs access control to the directory. I searched the ASP.NET Account. But I cannot find. How  Can i find or add? Any one please help

IF I try to add the ASPNET account using User Accounts panel. I cannot open the localusers It says an error "the computer is a domain controller. This snap-in cannot be used on a domail controller. Domain accounts are managed with active directory users and computers snap-in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing this command in command prompt:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnetregiis.exe -i -enable
```

Note that `v4.0.30319` will be different based on the .NET version you want.
If .NET 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5, it'll be `v2.0.50727` (because both use .NET 2.0 CLR).

Also, try right click my Computer, choose "Manage" and navigate to "System Tools", then "Local Users And Groups", then "users" for local users management of a machine even being memeber of a domain.

**Update:**

I assumed you know this, but just in case: Note that in Windows 2003, the ASP.NET account is not called "ASPNET" like Windows XP. It's called "NetworkService". Maybe this is the catch?

Comment: I tried this C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable
But i cannot see any ASPNET Machine account while clicking on the Find Now in Select Users, Computers or Group in Advanced tab for giving right to the directory

Comment: Check my update. If you are looking for ASPNET literally, that's not it, it's NetworkService instead.

Comment: So, does this answer your question? ;)

Comment: Yes I can use  Network service instead of ASPNET Machine account

Comment: Can you mark the reply then if it does answer your question correctly? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable
```

use dis command to create **asp.net machine account**

Answer (score 0):

Domain Controllers can't have local accounts. [This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;315158) is for ASP.NET 1.0, but I think it is still relevant to your problem. You'll have to set ASP.NET up to run either as the local system account or as a specific domain account.